# Golang: Sort the interface slice

Tags: sorting, go, interface, slice

I implemented an interface geometry and have a slice of it []geometry,

```
anything := []geometry{
        rect{width: 3, height: 4, name: "rect"},
        circle{radius: 5, name: "circle"},
}
```

now I want to sort the slice by name, change the sequence of elements in the slice. I can use getName function to get the name. After sorting, I want it like a slice like

```
{circle{radius: 5, name: "circle"},rect{width: 3, height: 4, name: "rect"},}
```

Here is the code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "sort"
)

type geometry interface {
    area() float64
    perim() float64
    getName() string
}

type rect struct {
    width, height float64
    name          string
}

type circle struct {
    radius float64
    name   string
}

func (r rect) area() float64 {
    return r.width * r.height
}
func (r rect) perim() float64 {
    return 2*r.width + 2*r.height
}
func (r rect) getName() string {
    return r.name
}

func (c circle) area() float64 {
    return math.Pi * c.radius * c.radius
}
func (c circle) perim() float64 {
    return 2 * math.Pi * c.radius
}
func (c circle) getName() string {
    return c.name
}

func main() {
    anything := []geometry{
        rect{width: 3, height: 4, name: "rect"},
        circle{radius: 5, name: "circle"},
    }
    for i := range anything {
        fmt.Println(anything[i].getName())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is an easy task for [`sort.Slice(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice) and is very similar to the example there!

All you need to do is call that function with your "anything" slice and a "Less" function which compares the result of `anything[x].getName()`.

For example ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/mGXY-4v67Nr)):

```
sort.Slice(anything, func(i, j int) bool {
  return anything[i].getName() < anything[j].getName()
})
// Now the items in "anything" are sorted alphabetically by name.
```